# Querying within lists in Mongo

Tags: mongodb

Assume the following structure:

```
'kitchenThings': [
    {'foods': [
        {'name': 'cakes',
         'ingredients': [
            {name: 'Sugar', healthy: false},
            {name: 'Butter', healthy: false},
            {name: 'Flour', healthy: true}
          ]
        }
    }
]
```

What query would I run to retrieve only kitchenThings that contain `healthy: false`? My first guess was

```
{ { 'foods.ingredients.healthy': false } }
```

but that returns 0 records. I'm not sure where to go from there. Can anyone help? My expected output is exactly as above, but with the non-matching ingredient (Flour) absent. Just returning the matching ingredients (presumably via a projection?) would be fine too.

Thanks

Comment: You want a document returned or only the array items where `healthy = true`?

Comment: An array of documents where healthy = true.

Comment: What your expect output?

Comment: @Yogesh - added to the question, thank you.

Comment: You are missing the 'kitchenThings' in the query: db.collection.find({'kitchenThings.foods.ingredients.healthy':false}). However, even if you are to query for *healthy: true* that doc will also be returned. So, maybe you want only a list of completely healthy foods, no?

Comment: @joao: Sorry, I should have been clearer, `kitchenThings` is the collection.

Answer (score 2):

To get a list of foods that contain **at least one** `healthy : false` ingredient you can use the [aggregation pipeline](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline/).

One possible solution might look like:

```
db.test.aggregate([
    {"$unwind": "$foods"},
    {"$match": {
        "foods.ingredients.healthy": false
    }},
    {"$project":{
        "_id": 0,
        "food": "$foods"
    }}
])
```

Test case:

```
db.test.insert({
    'foods': [
        {'name': 'cakes',
         'ingredients': [
            {name: 'Sugar', healthy: false},
            {name: 'Butter', healthy: false},
            {name: 'Flour', healthy: true}
          ]
        },
        {'name': 'fuits',
         'ingredients': [
            {name: 'Fiber', healthy: true},
            {name: 'Vitamins', healthy: true}
          ]
        },
        {'name': 'cookies',
         'ingredients': [
            {name: 'Sugar', healthy: false},
            {name: 'Butter', healthy: false},
            {name: 'Flour', healthy: true}
          ]
        },
    ]
})
```

Result:

```
{ "food" : { "name" : "cakes", "ingredients" : [ { "name" : "Sugar", "healthy" : false }, { "name" : "Butter", "healthy" : false }, { "name" : "Flour", "healthy" : true } ] } }
{ "food" : { "name" : "cookies", "ingredients" : [ { "name" : "Sugar", "healthy" : false }, { "name" : "Butter", "healthy" : false }, { "name" : "Flour", "healthy" : true } ] } }
```

Comment: Using $unwind as the first operator may cause performance problems and  also may take more time for processing. Am i right?? @joao

Comment: @manojpt Yes, depends on the number of documents you have to process. This data schema does 't give you much choice though. On the other hand, if you have something like a 'Foods' collection, you can do this query using a simple find.